# Find control inside layout template of ListView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can find control inside list view using this code

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

        // ...
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work when the control is in the layout template of the listView.How may I achieve this?

Here's my aspx markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="Pls_Questions" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Pls_Questions" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" OnPreRender="DataPager1_PreRender" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="1">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ButtonCssClass="Next" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ButtonCssClass="Prev" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton = "false" />
                                <asp:TemplatePagerField><PagerTemplate><br /></PagerTemplate></asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Button" NumericButtonCssClass="fq_pg" ButtonCount="999999999" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="ex__inn">
            <table>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="Lbl_question" data-quest='<%#Eval("question_number")%>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("question")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Image ID="__Image" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Ques_img")%>' onclick="return LoadDiv(this.src);" OnPreRender="__Image_PreRender" runat="server" />
                <input id="Btn__Essay" type="button" value="View Essay" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="opt_sw">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:Button ID="Bt__Null1" OnClick="Submit" Text="Null" style="display:none" runat="server"></asp:Button>
              </ContentTemplate><Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Bt__Null1" /></Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you provide the code for the layout as it would be easier to evaluate issue

Comment: Ok, I edited my post.

Comment: And in your sample mark-up, I don't see a Lable1 anyplace at all? Maybe because Lable1 does not exist in that sample page is the reason why the find control fails to find something that does not exist on the sample page is because it does not exist? Is there more code you are missing here?

Comment: Sorry, I removed it. It's now included in it.